# Trying to open a url stream in Octave?

Tags: java, matlab, octave

Trying to implement the Java in Octave Java Object... but not sure how to open a url stream?  thx

Java

```
  URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
  (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

---

Java in Octave ??

```
urlString = "http://www.google.com";
url = javaObject('java.net.URL',urlString);
stream = javaObject(url.openStream())  % <-------- ????? trying to do something like this
ireader = javaObject('java.io.InputStreamReader',stream);
```

When attempting:

```
stream = javaObject(url.openStream())
error: [java] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to fetch the contents, you can do something as easy as `urlread()`:

```
octave:3> a = urlread('google.com');
octave:4> a
a = <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">...
```

(Output truncated)

Help:

```
octave:6> help urlread
'urlread' is a function from the file /usr/lib/octave/3.6.4/oct/i686-redhat-linux-gnu/urlwrite.oct

 -- Loadable Function: S = urlread (URL)
 -- Loadable Function: [S, SUCCESS] = urlread (URL)
 -- Loadable Function: [S, SUCCESS, MESSAGE] = urlread (URL)
 -- Loadable Function: [...] = urlread (URL, METHOD, PARAM)
     Download a remote file specified by its URL and return its content
     in string S.  For example:

          s = urlread ("ftp://ftp.octave.org/pub/octave/README");

     The variable SUCCESS is 1 if the download was successful,
     otherwise it is 0 in which case MESSAGE contains an error message.
     If no output argument is specified and an error occurs, then the
     error is signaled through Octave's error handling mechanism.

     This function uses libcurl.  Curl supports, among others, the HTTP,
     FTP and FILE protocols.  Username and password may be specified in
     the URL.  For example:

          s = urlread ("http://user:password@example.com/file.txt");

     GET and POST requests can be specified by METHOD and PARAM.  The
     parameter METHOD is either `get' or `post' and PARAM is a cell
     array of parameter and value pairs.  For example:

          s = urlread ("http://www.google.com/search", "get",
                      {"query", "octave"});

     See also: urlwrite



Additional help for built-in functions and operators is
available in the online version of the manual.  Use the command
'doc <topic>' to search the manual index.

Help and information about Octave is also available on the WWW
at http://www.octave.org and via the help@octave.org
```

(Link to [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html), which Octave often mirrors)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Java Interface Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Java-Interface-Functions.html), you have to use `javaMethod` for this:

```
stream = javaMethod('openStream', url);
```